# Programmatic layouts showing error in landscape mode

Tags: ios, swift

[Here is the screenshot if the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbvtt.png)I am building the ui of the app programatically and when i run the app it runs perfectly but when i turn the simulation in landscape mode the console shows some layouts errors. Is it okay to just tick the orientation to portrait only in the general app settings  because my app is running perfectly in portrait mode and i don't want to run the app in any other orientations or am i making some problems in constraints? Here is my code for the ui...

`let top = UIColor(red: 217/255, green: 30/255, blue: 133/255, alpha: 1)
        let bottom = UIColor(red: 242/255, green: 56/255, blue: 15/255, alpha: 1)
        let colorOne = UIColor(red: 38/255, green: 38/255, blue: 38/255, alpha: 1)
        let colorTwo = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1)
        let colorTop = UIColor.red
        let colorBottom = UIColor.green

```
    let topContainer: UIView = {
        let top = UIView()
        top.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        top.backgroundColor = .black
        return top
    }()
    let model: UIImageView = {
        let mymodel = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "bodybuilder"))
        mymodel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        mymodel.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        return mymodel
    }()
    let logo: UIImageView = {
        let gymble = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Gymble"))
        gymble.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        gymble.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return gymble
    }()

    let bottomContainer: UIView = {
        let bottom = UIView()
        bottom.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return bottom
    }()

    let pinField: UITextField = {
        let phone = UITextField()
        phone.backgroundColor = .white
        phone.text = "+91"
        phone.textAlignment = .center
        phone.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        phone.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: 20)
        phone.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.numberPad
        phone.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return phone
    }()


    let phoneFeild: UITextField = {
        let phone = UITextField()
        phone.backgroundColor = .white
        phone.placeholder = "Phone number"
        phone.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        phone.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: 20)
        phone.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.phonePad
        phone.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearance.dark
        phone.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return phone
    }()

    let loginButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.setTitle("Login", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        button.layer.masksToBounds = true
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Medium", size: 22)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(someButtonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

    let laterButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.setTitle("I'll login later", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.gray, for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Light", size: 16)
        return button
    }()

    let horizontalStack: UIStackView = {
        let mystack = UIStackView()
        mystack.alignment = UIStackView.Alignment.center
        mystack.axis = NSLayoutConstraint.Axis.horizontal
        mystack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        mystack.distribution = .fill
        mystack.spacing = 15
        return mystack
    }()

    let stack: UIStackView = {
        let mystack = UIStackView()
        mystack.alignment = UIStackView.Alignment.center
        mystack.axis = NSLayoutConstraint.Axis.vertical
        mystack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        mystack.distribution = .equalSpacing
        return mystack
    }()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .black

        view.addSubview(topContainer)
        topContainerLayout()

        topContainer.addSubview(model)
        modelLayout()

        view.addSubview(bottomContainer)
        bottomContainerLayout()

        bottomContainer.addSubview(stack)
        stackLayout()

        stack.addArrangedSubview(logo)
        logoLayout()

        stack.addArrangedSubview(horizontalStack)
        horizontalStackLayout()
        horizontalStack.addArrangedSubview(pinField)
        pinFieldLayout()

        let padding = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 15, height: self.phoneFeild.frame.height))
        phoneFeild.leftView = padding
        phoneFeild.leftViewMode = UITextField.ViewMode.always
        horizontalStack.addArrangedSubview(phoneFeild)
        phoneFieldLayout()


        let gradientWidth = (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 32)
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = [top.cgColor, bottom.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.15, 1]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
        gradientLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: gradientWidth, height: 50)
        gradientLayer.cornerRadius = 5
        loginButton.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)

        stack.addArrangedSubview(loginButton)
        loginButtonLayout()

        stack.addArrangedSubview(laterButton)
        LaterButtonLayout()

    }

    func LaterButtonLayout(){
        laterButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    }

    func loginButtonLayout(){
        loginButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stack.widthAnchor, constant: -32).isActive = true
        loginButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true
    }

    func logoLayout(){
        logo.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stack.topAnchor).isActive = true
        logo.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 56).isActive = true
        logo.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
    }

    func stackLayout(){
        stack.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomContainer.heightAnchor).isActive = true
        stack.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomContainer.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    func horizontalStackLayout(){
        horizontalStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
        horizontalStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
        horizontalStack.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
    }
    func pinFieldLayout(){
        pinField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: horizontalStack.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        pinField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: horizontalStack.topAnchor).isActive = true
        pinField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: horizontalStack.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        pinField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    }
    func phoneFieldLayout(){
        phoneFeild.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pinField.trailingAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
        phoneFeild.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: horizontalStack.topAnchor).isActive = true
        phoneFeild.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: horizontalStack.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    func modelLayout(){
        model.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topContainer.topAnchor).isActive = true
        model.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topContainer.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        model.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topContainer.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        model.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topContainer.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    }


    func bottomContainerLayout(){
        bottomContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topContainer.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        bottomContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        bottomContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        bottomContainer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    func topContainerLayout(){
        topContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        topContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 2/3 , constant: -20).isActive = true
        topContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        topContainer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    @objc func someButtonAction(){
        print("Button is tapped!")
        let opt = OTPViewController()
        present(opt, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
`
```

Comment: Add your error and code related to UI.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you didn't make auto layout.

- Please check this out -> [Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html)
- And this -> [Programmatically Creating Constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH16-SW1)

Edit:
Use that `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` after addSubView.For example

```
func topContainerLayout(){
    topContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    topContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    topContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 2/3 , constant: -20).isActive = true
    topContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    topContainer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

Comment: I have added this property in the closure of the top container.

Comment: I know, i just said delete it from property and add to topContainerLayout function. And do it for all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize app orientation do this: 
Go to **General** setting of project 
in **Deployment** , change device orientation .